# Why don't my motors rotate?

Tags: dc-motor

I know I asked this question before, but this time I will give a more clearer description. I have been using the raspberry pi for approximately 6 months now. I am making a very simple robot car that includes a motor and ultrasonic sensor circuit. The ultrasonic sensor works perfectly but the motors aren't spinning with my circuit and programs. Please help:

Info and details:
I am using a 9v battery, and l298n, 2 DC Motors and the raspberry pi and some wires for the motor circuit. You can see the circuit in the picture below made using the app fritzing:
[image]

Then I programmed the circuit using the raspberry pi using python and the RPi.GPIO library / module. The code is below:

```
# importing all modules
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Setting up gpio pins for output
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(31, GPIO.OUT)

# Moving the car/ rotating the motor
# This part just moves the car front for 2 secs then back for 2 secs

GPIO.output(37, True)
GPIO.output(33, True)
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(37, False)
GPIO.output(33, False)
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(35, True)
GPIO.output(31, True)
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(35, False)
GPIO.output(31, False)

# Cleaning up
GPIO.cleanup()
```

There are no errors in the code when I run it (If there are in the code above, then that's probably true because I didn't copy and paste the code, I just wrote it here, so there might be a typo or something). The program just doesn't do anything. I ran it on idle in the raspberry pi. Please help, any good help will be useful thank you! Thank you as it means a lot!!

Comment: I have told you what is wrong with the code.  I suggest you read my comment on your previous question.

Comment: Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: As I understood, You are setting one pin high and low to run and stop the motor. But what about second pin state? what is the default state? Always provide either pull-up or pull-down to the other pin. Ex: if pin no. 37 and 35 are controlling a single motor, then set one pin high and another pin low. And do the same with second motor. Do not put the pins in default of float state. You can also set the pull-up/pull-down while configuring the pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I asked this question before, but this time I will give a more
>   clearer description.

I know [I answered this question before](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95999/why-isn-t-my-raspberry-pi-motor-spinning), but this time I will give a more clearer description link.

[Robot buggy - Assembling the motors and board - projects.raspberrypi.org](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/build-a-buggy/2)

[image: robot buggy]

I have also assembled a 16450 power bank for my L298N robot buggy

[image: power bank 16450]

Comment: Yeah, I would have also tried to improve your last answer although I could see you put a lot of effort into answering my question! Thank you and your website gave a lot of information!