# Can I use 12v and 8amp battery with L298 motor driver

Tags: power-supply, pi-4

Can I use 12v and 8amp battery with L298 motor driver with raspberry pi model?

Comment: I would suggest to follow Rpi's "official" tutorial on how to use L298N:https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98513/program-my-robot-with-python. You might also like to search this forum with key word "L298N" for more than ten posts, on how to use L298N and similar drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Make sure you don't connect anything over 3V3 to a Pi GPIO though, and don't try to power the Pi from the L298 module or the 12V power supply.

Comment: Thanks Joan, the power source for the RPI is separate, i.e power adapter using pi's type c port. And from 12v battery I have to run a cars power window motor which need around 8amp current to run properly. So is it okay to run? and can you please tell me more about what you said about 3V3 GPIO pins as I'm new to all this stuff?

Comment: With the exception of two pins connected to the Pi's 5V power rail, all the GPIO pins either produce or expect 3.3 volts.  They are not tolerant of higher voltages, and an attempt to use 12V, or even 5V, as a signal input to a GPIO pin is likely to fry your Pi.

Comment: The L298N can't feed 8 amps (I assumed that was the battery capacity rating).  It can only handle a couple of amps.  If you need to supply 8 amps you need a different motor driver board (probably one rated for 12 amps at least).

Comment: Yes Joan, I found that the L298 module does not giving enough current to the motor. So I have to change the motor driver.